# Blackberry and Facebook Like button (mobile web)

Tags: blackberry, mobile-website, facebook-like

If using xfbml, the Facebook Like button doesn't even render on Blackberrys.
If using iframe, the Facebook Like button shows up, but clicking on it doesn't do anything.

Our only solution is to just manually give them a link to their Facebook page based on browser detection.

Anyone running into issues with this?
Anyone have any other solutions or fixes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You issue might have something to do with the Blackberry's browser ignoring tags it doesn't understand. I would suggest using the newer HTML5 versions of the plugins since from my experience they are more reliable.  (or you could use the iframe html)